# Flatten Bumpy Stickers After Heated

Tags: adhesive

I recently switched laptops and used a hairdryer to remove stickers from my laptop.  I now want to restick them on my new laptop but some are a bit bumpy.

What's the best way to smooth them out without damaging them?

Answer (score 2):

Use a credit card when applying. Sort of scrape it flat, with a fair bit of pressure so no air is trapped underneath.

If the sticker is already placed, you should probably re-stick them. Or try scraping it flat, because you have to remove the air. But don't force the bubbles or lumps if they are stubborn as you may stretch or rip it.

I just thought, you could use your hairdryer, while flattening the sticker with a credit card, to melt the glue a bit.

Comment: You could also slice the bubble with a razor and then flatten that.

Comment: This is good, although the stickers are already bumpy.  When I was pulling them off they stretched a little.

Answer (score -5):

Use something to hammer them flat. It won't damage the stickers ( as you requested) , but I can't say the same for the laptop.